# Using YouTube API in AngularJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm just trying to do some simple calls on youtube videos such as using their seekTo() method and getTimeStamp() sort of thing. I'm struggling to follow the documentation and was wondering if anyone knew of any example code I could look at?

e.g. Working with embedded videos -

Currently using -

Is it as simple as adding enablejsapi=1 like so?

link = http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1

How exactly do you call methods such as seekTo() etc. then? Sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: Have you read the API documentation? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

As JCD indicated as well, the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en) is a great starting point for what you might need to do.

It goes into detail on where to start, how to load videos, JS functions used, etc.

[`seekTo(...)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#seekTo) requires 2 parameters, `seconds` and `allowSeekAhead`. Its recommended to set `allowSeekAhead` to `false` when the user is dragging the progress bar and `true` when user releases it.

Comment: Using the first example in the documentation seems to be returning a blank page for some reason. I've noticed there's no mention of where to use the API key. Is that likely the reason or is it simply not needed?

Comment: When using the iframe API, you wont need any API key since you're embedding the YouTube player itself.

Regarding the blank page, I cannot replicate the issue you're experiencing as it works fine when I tested the whole sample code.